# Possible to use http basic authentication with AWS CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, yum, basic-authentication

I am attempting to put a CloudFront Distribution in front of a Yum (RPM) repo which uses basic http authentication. I've setup the CloudFront Distribution w/ HTTPS, redirection from HTTP to HTTPS, with the following values:

```
Origin: yum.mydomain.com
Origin ID: smp-yum.mydomain.com
```

Note: smp-yum.mydomain.com does not exist right now, I am not sure if it needs to?

For testing purposes I am strictly using the abcdefgh.cloudfront.net domain.

I am getting the following error trying to visit the URL:

```
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection.
```

Because I know the host is up, and accepts connections from the public internet, I can only assume that it is due to the http basic auth.

I have also attempted to include the credentials into the request, via

```
https://username:password@yum.mydomain.com/repo/url
```

I suppose this is a two-part question: Is it possible to use HTTP Basic Auth? and if so, is there some headers or something that I need to customize in order to make it work?

Comment: In the Cache Behavior settings, did you whitelist the `Authorization` header?  Note that CloudFront isn't going to cache much when HTTP Basic authentication is used... it would only serve the cached responses if the same pages are requested again using the same credentials.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Initially not; good catch.  But after whitelisting the Authorization header I am still receiving the same result.  The restrictions listed wouldn't be an issue, as each customer has its own set of credentials and it's own packages.  The advantage would come in the fact that the application is installed on multiple servers for each client.

Comment: Be sure you observe the `Age:` header (age, in seconds, of the cached response) when testing.  Realizing that you have been troubleshooting against a cached response is not fun.  If you are still getting "either the attempt failed..." that is often caused by an SSL misconfiguration (self-signed cert, cert signed by a sketchy CA that CloudFront doesn't trust, or subject mismatch).  At least one of (a) the Host header that is sent (if whitelisted) *or* (b) the configured origin domain name must match the certificate offered by the origin server.